# Python If elif else

Tags: python, loops, nested

`

```
is_summer = True
 print("Values 1-12 correlate to the months of the year")
 while is_summer == True:
     _month = int(input("Enter the month of the year: "))
     if _month == 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8:                 
         is_summer = int(input("It is summer, what is the temperature?: "))
         if is_summer in range(60,101):                  
             print("The squirrels are playing")
         else:
             print("The squirells are not playing")      
     elif _month == 1 or 2 or 3 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12:   
         is_summer = int(input("It is winter, what is the temperature?: "))
         if is_summer in range(60,91):
             print("The squirrels are playing")           
         else:
             print("The squirrels are not playing")
    `
```

My code will not go down to the elif statement if i enter 1,2,3,9,10,11,or 12. Are my nested if statements done incorrectly, or is it something else?

Comment: A more elegant solution would be to use `in` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your code is not executing as you expect is because you are not actually checking if `_month` equals each of the numbers.

`if _month == 1 or 2 or 3` is not the same as `if _month == 1 or _month == 2 or _month == 3`.

Think of the first as `if (_month == 1) or (2) or (3)`. `_month == 1` evaluates to `False`, but `2` or `3` are non-zero values that evaluate to `True`, so the first `if` is always taken.

Answer (score 1):

Your conditional statements work as follows which is the reason why the condition is not always true for the input you provide.

```
>>> month = 4
>>> month == 4 or 5 or 6
True
>>> month = 5
>>> month == 4 or 5 or 6
5
```

You could use the `in` operator to check whether the `_month` exists in the list of values you're using the `or` check for. The `in` operator works as follows

```
month = 1
month in [1,2,3,4,5] # True
month in [2,3,4,5,6] # False
```

Therefore you could change your program to be

```
is_summer = True
print("Values 1-12 correlate to the months of the year")
while is_summer == True:
    _month = int(input("Enter the month of the year: "))
    if _month in [4,5,6,7,8]:                 
        is_summer = int(input("It is summer, what is the temperature?: "))
        if is_summer in range(60,101):                  
            print("The squirrels are playing")
        else:
            print("The squirells are not playing")      
    elif _month in [1,2,3,9,10,11,12]:   
        is_summer = int(input("It is winter, what is the temperature?: "))
        if is_summer in range(60,91):
            print("The squirrels are playing")           
        else:
            print("The squirrels are not playing")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with your if statements.

```
if _month == 4 or 5 or 6 or 7 or 8:
```

This checks if _month == 4, or if 5 is truthy, or if 6 is truthy etc.

You want to be doing:

```
if _month == 4 or _month ==5 or _month == 6 or _month == 7 or _month == 8:
```

or more concise

```
if 4 <= _month <= 8:
```

Do the same for your elif. Although if you know _month is goin to be from 1 to 12, then really it can probably just be an else, instead of an elif

Answer (score 1):

Your first `if` statement is basically saying if `_month` is 4 – great – or if 5 or 6 or 7 or 8 will evaluate to `True`. In an if statement in Python, positive integers will always evaluate to `True` –

```
if 1:
  print("hello!")
```

will always print `hello!`. Your `if` statement needs to look like this, instead:

```
if _month == 4 or _month == 5 or _month == 6 or _month == 7 or _month == 8:
  print("hurrah!")
```

This is getting needlessly verbose, however – we can simplify this using comparison operators like less-than (`>`) and greater-than (`<`), like so:

```
if _month < 3 and _month > 9:
  print("hurrah!")
```